# Find Maximum Value of Regions of Unknown size in an Array using CUDA

Tags: c++, c, arrays, cuda, thrust

Say I have an array `A[4000]` of values that contains all different numbers `[45,21,764,234,7,0,12,55,...]`

Then I have another array `B[4000]` that denotes the location of regions in array `A` with the number `1` if it is a part of a region, and `0` if it is not. If the `1's` are next to each other that means they are part of the same region, if they are not next to each other (there is a `0` in between the `1's`) then they are part of a different region.

ex. `B = [1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0...]` Means that I want to find the maximum value in the region of the `first three numbers in array A`, and the maximum number in the `5th and 6th numbers in array A, etc.`
So that I can produce an array `C[4000]` that holds the maximum values of `A` in each of the regions denoted by `B`, and a `0` in the areas that are not part of the regions.

So in this case `C = [764,764,764,0,7,7,0,0...]`

There can be anywhere from `0 to 2,000 regions`, and the length of the regions can range from `2 to 4,000 numbers long`. I never know beforehand how many regions there are or the different sizes of the regions.

I have been trying to come up with a kernel in CUDA that can achieve this result. It needs to be done as fast as possible since it in reality it will be used for images, this is just a simplified example. All of my ideas, such as using reduction, only work if there is only one region spans all `4000` numbers of array `A`. However, I do not think that I can use reduction here because there can be multiple regions in the array separated by `1` to `3996` spaces (`0's`) and reduction will cause me to loose track of the separated regions. Or, the kernel has far too many loops and if statements in it to be fast such as

```
int intR = 0;
 while(B[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + intR] > 0){
     intMaxR = intMaxR < A[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + intR] ? A[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + intR] : intMaxR;
     intR++;
 }

 int intL = 0;
 while(B[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x - intL] > 0){
     intMaxL = intMaxL < A[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x - intL] ? A[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + intL] : intMaxL;
     intL++;
 }

 intMax =  intMaxR > intMaxL ? intMaxR : intMaxL;

 for(int i = 0; i < intR; i++){
     C[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + i] = intMax;
 }
 for(int i = 0; i < intL; i++){
     C[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x - i] = intMax;
 }
```

Clearly the code is slow even with shared memory, and isn't really taking advantage of the parallel nature of CUDA. Does anyone have any idea on how or if this can be done efficiently in CUDA?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) function [reduce_by_key](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga1fd25c0e5e4cc0a6ab0dcb1f7f13a2ad) to help with this.

Comment: That would help in finding the maximum values for the regions, but wouldn't I still lose my locations or have to basically iterate through the whole array to fill in where the regions are which would not be very parallel

Comment: Yes, I was not suggesting it was a complete solution.  I have added an answer showing how it might be used in a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach would be to use [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

A possible sequence would be like this:

1. use
   [thrust::reduce_by_key](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga1fd25c0e5e4cc0a6ab0dcb1f7f13a2ad)
   to generate the max values for each range.
2. use thrust::adjacent_difference to delineate the start of each range
3. use an inclusive scan on the results of step 2 to generate the gather indices, i.e. the indices that will be used to select the reduced value (results from step 1) that will go in each location of the output vector.
4. Use [thrust::gather_if](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__gathering.html#gaf7acd33a67b2313a651ee19f3ac5cd04) to selectively place the reduced values into appropriate locations (where there is a 1 in the B vector) in the output vector, using the gather indices generated in step 3.

Here's a fully worked code demonstrating this, using A and B vectors like your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/adjacent_difference.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/transform_scan.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#define DSIZE 8

template <typename T>
struct abs_val : public thrust::unary_function<T, T>
{
  __host__ __device__
  T operator()(const T& x) const
  {
    if (x<0) return -x;
    else return x;
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct subtr : public thrust::unary_function<T, T>
{
  const T val;
  subtr(T _val): val(_val) {}
  __host__ __device__
  T operator()(const T& x) const
  {
    return  x-val;
  }
};

int main(){

  int A[DSIZE] = {45,21,764,234,7,0,12,55};
  int B[DSIZE] = {1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0};
  thrust::device_vector<int> dA(A, A+DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> dB(B, B+DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> dRed(DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> diffB(DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> dRes(DSIZE);

  thrust::reduce_by_key(dB.begin(), dB.end(), dA.begin(), thrust::make_discard_iterator(), dRed.begin(), thrust::equal_to<int>(), thrust::maximum<int>());
  thrust::adjacent_difference(dB.begin(), dB.end(), diffB.begin());
  thrust::transform_inclusive_scan(diffB.begin(), diffB.end(), diffB.begin(), abs_val<int>(), thrust::plus<int>());
  thrust::gather_if(thrust::make_transform_iterator(diffB.begin(), subtr<int>(B[0])), thrust::make_transform_iterator(diffB.end(), subtr<int>(B[0])), dB.begin(), dRed.begin(), dRes.begin());
  thrust::copy(dRes.begin(), dRes.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout  << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Notes about the example:

1. reduce_by_key is generating reduced values (maximums) for each
   consecutive 0 sequence *or* 1 sequence in B.  You only really need
   the maximums for the 1 sequences.  We will discard the 0 sequence
   maximums via the gather_if function.
2. I allow for the possibility that the B vector may start with either
   a 1 sequence or a 0 sequence, by using the transform_iterator
   treatment of the vector result of step 2, subtracting the first
   value of the B vector from each gather index.
3. The adjacent_difference operation will produce either a 1 or -1 to
   delineate the start of a new sequence.  I use the
   transform_inclusive_scan variant with the abs_val functor to treat these equally, for scan purposes (i.e. generation of gather indices).
4. The above code should produce results matching your desired `C` output vector, like this:

   ```
   $ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t53 t53.cu
   $ ./t53
   764 764 764 0 7 7 0 0
   $
   ```

We can use [thrust::placeholders](http://thrust.github.io/doc/namespaceplaceholders.html) to further simplify the above code, eliminating the need for the extra functor definitions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/adjacent_difference.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/transform_scan.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#define DSIZE 2000000
using namespace thrust::placeholders;

typedef int mytype;

int main(){

  mytype *A = (mytype *)malloc(DSIZE*sizeof(mytype));
  int *B = (int *)malloc(DSIZE*sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++){
    A[i] = (rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*10.0f;
    B[i] = rand()%2;}
  thrust::device_vector<mytype> dA(A, A+DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> dB(B, B+DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<mytype> dRed(DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> diffB(DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<mytype> dRes(DSIZE);

  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  cudaEventCreate(&start);
  cudaEventCreate(&stop);
  cudaEventRecord(start);
  thrust::reduce_by_key(dB.begin(), dB.end(), dA.begin(), thrust::make_discard_iterator(), dRed.begin(), thrust::equal_to<mytype>(), thrust::maximum<mytype>());
  thrust::adjacent_difference(dB.begin(), dB.end(), diffB.begin());
  thrust::transform_inclusive_scan(diffB.begin(), diffB.end(), diffB.begin(), _1*_1, thrust::plus<int>());
  thrust::gather_if(thrust::make_transform_iterator(diffB.begin(), _1 - B[0]), thrust::make_transform_iterator(diffB.end(), _1 - B[0]), dB.begin(), dRed.begin(), dRes.begin());
  cudaEventRecord(stop);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  float et;
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);
  std::cout<< "elapsed time: " << et << "ms " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(dRes.begin(), dRes.begin()+10, std::ostream_iterator<mytype>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout  << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

(I've modified the above placeholders code to also include generation of a larger size data set, as well as some basic timing apparatus.)

Comment: This code definitely works and it's a good answer. However, I finally got a chance to test the timing of this code and it is way too slow to actually use on images. Is there a possible way to speed this up?

Comment: I upped the `DSIZE` to 2000000 (i.e. a proxy for a 1920x1080 image), generated arbitrary data, and wrapped `cudaEvent` timing around the 4 key thrust calls (reduce through gather), and the timing was ~2.5ms on a K40, ~3ms on a C2075, and ~20ms on a Quadro NVS 310 (cc2.1, 1 SM, i.e. a tiny GPU). 60fps would require less than 16ms per frame for processing, not including data transfer time or other overheads (which could presumably be pipelined).  I don't have any immediate suggestions to speed it up other than to use a fast GPU.

Comment: I've modified the placeholders version of the code shown in my answer to demonstrate the timing and analysis I discuss in the comment above.

Comment: Sadly this is part of a much larger program that already has other functions and kernels in it so this has to take less than 1ms. Looks like I need to pipeline or find a way to shave time off of my other kernels. Thanks for the help!

Comment: A video processing algorithm could probably also efficiently use 2 (or more) GPUs by distributing images to be processed to GPUs in a round-robin fashion.